# How to make a quarter circle polar plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a two-column data as below that I really need to create a bar polar chart from (a quarter circle polar plot from zero to 90 degree).

```
Angle   Frequency   
0-10    83.3
10_20   16.6
20_30   5.7
30_40   62.3
40_50   32.4
```

I tried using `ggplot2` as below, but it creates a 360 degree circle. I could not find how to make it a quarter circle (not a 360 degree circle).

```
d <- structure(list(Angle = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
                Frequency = c(83.3, 16.6, 5.7, 62.3, 32.4)), .Names = c("Angle", "Frequency"),
           row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(d, aes(x = Angle, y = Frequency)) +
coord_polar(theta = "x", start = -pi/36, direction = 1) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,90), breaks = seq(0, 90, 10))
```

I also tried using `plotly` as below:

```
library("plotly")
p <- plot_ly(
  type = 'barpolar',
  r = c(54.7, 32.6, 8.4, 10.4, 30.6),
  theta = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40)) %>% 
    layout(
    polar = list(
      radialaxis = list(
        visible = T,
        range = c(0,60)
      ),
      sector = c(0,90),
      radialaxis = list(
        tickfont = list(
          size = 10
        )
      ),
      angularaxis = list(
        tickfont = list(
          size = 10
        )
      )
    )
)
```

However, I need to change some features of the created bar polar chart using `plotly`, and I could not find how to modify them.

Here are my questions:

**For the figure made using `ggplot2`**: how can I make a quarter circle (rather than a full 360-degree circle)?

**For the figure made using `plotly`:**

1) How do I modify the interval of the bins? In my current chart, angles are divided into 15 degree increments: 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, and 90 degrees. I need to change this interval to 10 and make the divisions 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, and 90. How can I do that?

2) How can I change the colour of the bars? Now all five bars are blue, but I want to change the blue colour, for example, to black, red, or any colour.

I would highly appreciate your great and valuable help. Many thanks.

Comment: for the color, add `marker = list(
    color = "red"
  )` to the plot_ly